# Excluding URLs from Django redirects

Tags: django, nginx

Im redirecting all my files on the root of my site to the English subdirectory

```
url(r'^(?P<zero>([a-z-]*)).(htm|php|html)$', redirect, {'to': '/en/{0}.html', 'permanent': True}),
```

I want to exclude a specific page.   If I were using apache I could easily do this with an alias or a mod rewrite before it hits the Django application.  However Im using Nginx and the redirect gets process regardless of the alias.  Is there a rule I can use above so a specific page on my root won't get redirected?

the following is an example of my config with using regx,  tried it with suggested one above as well (location ^~ /file.html { )

```
 listen 8007;
    server_name  devel.somedomain.com;
    access_log  /var/log/nginx/somedomain-dev.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
    real_ip_header X-Forwarded-For;
    set_real_ip_from 0.0.0.0/0;
    #real_ip_recursive on;

    location ~ /help.cgi$  {

        proxy_pass http://localhost:8006;
    }

    location ^~* /file\.html$ {
        alias /home/admin/somedomain/file.html;
    }
    location / {
       proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8006;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's even easier in nginx.

```
location ^~ /file_name {
     alias /path/to/file_name;
}
```

Put that before the `proxy_pass`.

Comment: tried this in several different ways, Django redirect keeps processing the url afterwards

Comment: Show your config.

Comment: I realized I wasn't restarting Nginx properly,  once I add it started working